# Why is my sed multiline find-and-replace not working as expected?

Tags: sed, replace

I have a simple *sed* command that I am using to replace everything between (and including) `//thistest.com--` and `--thistest.com` with **nothing** (remove the block all together):

```
sudo sed -i "s@//thistest\.com--.*--thistest\.com@@g" my.file
```

The contents of `my.file` are:

```
//thistest.com--
zone "awebsite.com" {
         type master;
         file "some.stuff.com.hosts";
         };

//--thistest.com
```

As I am using `@` as my delimiter for the regex, I don't need to escape the `/` characters. I am also properly (I think) escaping the `.` in `.com`. So I don't see exactly what is failing.

Why isn't the entire block being replaced?

Comment: Sed operates a line at a time. You can't match a multiline pattern that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Sed doesn't do multiline pattern matches—at least, not the way you're expecting it to. However, you can use multiline *addresses* as an alternative.
2. Depending on your version of sed, you may need to escape alternate delimiters, especially if you aren't using them solely as part of a substitution expression.

So, the following will work with your posted corpus in both GNU and BSD flavors:

```
sed '\@^//thistest\.com--@, \@^//--thistest\.com@ d' /tmp/corpus
```

Note that in this version, we tell sed to match all lines between (and including) the two patterns. The opening delimiter of each address pattern is properly escaped. The command has also been changed to `d` for *delete* instead of `s` for *substitute*, and some whitespace was added for readability.

I've also chosen to anchor the address patterns to the start of each line. You may or may not find that helpful with this specific corpus, but it's generally wise to do so when you can, and doesn't seem to hurt your use case.

Comment: The only thing I will add is that I changed to double quotes for use of variables so that, `thistestsite.com` can be a variable etc etc .. thx for the multi-line explanation -- the manuals I was reading on `sed` never mentioned "single line only"!

Answer (score 0):

```
# separation by line with 1 s//
sed -n -e 'H;${x;s#^\(.\)\(.*\)\1//thistest.com--.*\1//--thistest.com#\2#;p}' YourFile

# separation by line with address pattern
sed -e '\#//thistest.com--#,\#//--thistest.com# d' YourFile

# separation only by char (could be CR, CR/LF, ";" or "oneline") with s//
sed -n -e '1h;1!H;${x;s#//thistest.com--.*\1//--thistest.com##;p}' YourFile
```

Note:

- assuming there is only 1 section *thistest* per file (if not, it remove anything between the first opening until the last closing section) for the use of s//
- does not suite for huge file (load entire file into memory) with s//
- sed using addresses pattern cannot select section on the same line, it search 1st pattern to start, and a following line to stop but very efficient on big file and/or multisection